# back pressed from menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a settings menu which is used in all of the screen in the application. Now when I click the menu and go to the particular screen edit come settings and press back then I'm unable to know from which screen the menu item was clicked.
I tried to put the activity name in intent but it doesn't sound like good idea..
Please help.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.propsmain);
    setTitle("Settings");
    prev_screen = getIntent().getStringExtra("prev_screen");
    try {
        final ArrayList<Properties> propsList = getProperties();
        if (propsList == null || propsList.size() == 0) {
                       // show alert
        } else {
            setListAdapter(new PropertyAdapter(this, R.layout.props,
                    propsList));
        }
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            // @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Properties prop = propsList.get(arg2);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("prop_name", prop.getName());
                b.putString("prop_value", prop.getValue());

                Intent intent = new Intent(SetProperties.this,
                            EditPropertyActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        });

    } catch (PropertyFileMissing e) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SetProperties.this)
                .create();
        dialog.setTitle("Failure");
        dialog.setMessage(e.toString());
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error);
        dialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    } 
}
```

// EditProperty class this has a dialogtheme in my manifest

```
    ublic class EditPropertyActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    setTitle("");
    TextView propName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_propName);
    final String tagName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("prop_name");
    final String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("prop_value");

    propName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("prop_label"));

    final EditText ed_propValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_propValue);
    ed_propValue.setText(value);
    if (tagName.equals("timeout")) {
        ed_propValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    }
    Button btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        // @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newValue = ed_propValue.getText().toString().trim();
            if ((tagName.equals("timeout") || tagName.equals("serverUrl") || tagName
                    .equals("channelName")) && (newValue.equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.NOT_NULL),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            editFile(tagName, newValue);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        // @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

--Abhilasha

Comment: why dont you simply call `finish();` when back is pressed? doing so will cause to go one activity back from stack

Comment: sorry, I should have added this in my question. My menu has an option Settings, when I click it, it opens a list view, now on click of an item it open a dialog to edit that item. So the solution which is given above i.e to call finish() doesn't work if I edit like 3 to 4 items.In this case when I press back it just goes back to my to my settings screen only which I donot want.

Comment: currently I am passing the activity name from which the menu was clicked and in my Settings activity I call the activity depending on name....Lots of if else statements..:( It works absolutely fine..But I want to know is there any other way to do it...

Comment: Let me rephrase it, I have Activity <b>S</b> screen which is a ListView. I call this activity from another activity <b>A</b>. On click of an item it shows up a dialog where i can set a new value to the item.Consider I edit 3 items ..the stack is like A->S->S->S...this is my problem. I press back and it should go from S->A

Comment: put your all code. all are confused what you want to do actually. one more thing you say you use dialog for edit item. when you edit item 3 then stack goes A->S->S->S. so problem in edit. you open dialog not a Activity then why its happen??

Comment: Now I have added code for my Settings Activity and the EditProperty class in which I edit the selected list item. If I edit one item and press back it works fine. If I edit two or more items in Settings screen and I press back then again Settings screen is displayed

Comment: If I use inline `finish()` my settings screen is not updated with latest value of the item edited. I'm even updating the list in inline `onResume()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the delay for posting the answer. I had problems 
using the method below fixed the issue.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(count == 0){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

and also after I click save button on my dialog activity , I added below code to update the value of the item selected.And instead of starting the activity again with a new intent , I just call 'finish();` as Waqas suggested.

```
    SetProperties.propsList = getProperties();
    PropertyAdapter adapter = (PropertyAdapter) SetProperties.listview.getAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    finish();
```

Thanks all for the help and guidance :)